# How to get Account Lead Contact and Task details in a Polymorphic SOQL

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a lwc datatable in which i am trying to display Contact, Account, Lead and task details. I am able to send Contact , Lead and Task in same list. Is it possible using polymorhic SOQL , we can send Account details also in same query?

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<Task>  getRecords(){
    List<Task> latestTasks = new List<Task>();
    
    List<Task> taskList = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Call_Block___c , Scheduled_Follow_Up__c , Status, Subject, TYPEOF who
                           WHEN Contact THEN Name, Phone
                           WHEN Lead THEN Id, Name, Company, Phone, Industry, CreatedDate, State , Country, Postalcode , Street, City
                           END
                           FROM Task WHERE Type = 'To Sync' ];
    system.debug('taskList ' + taskList);
    return taskList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task has a field built for what you want, helpfully named Account.

As an example:

```
return [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Call_Block___c , Scheduled_Follow_Up__c, Status, Subject, 
   Account.Name, Account.Phone, Account.Website,
   TYPEOF who
     WHEN Contact THEN Name, Phone
     WHEN Lead THEN Id, Name, Company, Phone, Industry, CreatedDate, State , Country, Postalcode , Street, City
   END
   FROM Task WHERE Type = 'To Sync' ];
```

There's no need for polymorphism to get the Account.

This field returns the Contact, Case, or Opportunity's Account record fields, as you'd expect.

Comment: thanks sfdcfox..